# How do I make my mesh move 1-1 with the bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Whenever I move the bone on my rig the mesh moves but almost never 1-1. How come that happens. I checked to make sure all location, rotation, and scaling are set to zero. I've tried re-parenting, and I have tried painting the whole hand red which has little to no better results than just painting the wrist red.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The effect of the armature on the mesh is an accumulation of *all* bones - to make a section of your mesh follow the action of a single bone you do need to ensure the weights for that single bone are all at 1.0, but also you need to ensure that the weights for that section of mesh are zero for all other bones - otherwise the other bones will also be affecting its deformation, negating some of the effect.